# Lightning Design system elements

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, slds

This might be a very silly question, but I wanted to make sure that I am not doing anything wrong.

I am using SLDS to design all my components and has been using js to add necessary classes to perform required action. For example, I had to add **`slds-is-open`** class to open a menu item etc.

Is that the right behaviour or the elements should automatically include required class, similar to bootstrap.

Comment: You can try [http://aljs.appiphony.com/](http://aljs.appiphony.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. LDS is a CSS library and we need to write JavaScript on top of it to add desired behavior. Bootstrap comes with JavaScript handlers and code as well(at places) but Lightning is just a CSS library.

This question in FAQ has the answer to what you are looking for: [Is any JavaScript included as part of the framework?](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/faq/#is-any-java-script-included-as-part-of-the-framework)

Comment: I should I have read the SLDS FAQ's before posting here. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't checked lately, review the lightning: components listed in the [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm) and use those where possible. They have the SLDS class handling JavaScript built in and so save you a lot of work.

This [Base Components Roadmap](https://www.meetup.com/Dublin-Salesforce-Developer-Group/photos/27854570/#460997442) suggests that most commonly used components will be available by the end of 2017 (subject to the usual [Forward-Looking Statements](http://investor.salesforce.com/about-us/investor/forward-looking-statements/) caveat).

Comment: I am aware of these, but definitely we need more elements when building components. Thanks for the help.